# Typescript - Unable to splice array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to remove part of an array when a checkbox is unchecked (if the checkbox value matches a value in an array item). The array which is created when the user clicks on a checkbox(es) works fine but when a checkbox is unchecked, the array object I'm attempting to remove/splice is now a string Object so it can't be spliced. My confusion is in regards to why the array "turns" into a string Object after a second loop.

The main block of code I'm struggling with starts at: **onCheckboxChange(option, event)**

Stackblitz is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-match-groceries-sweets

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
// import * as d3 from "d3";
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  grocery_list: any;
  treats: [];
  box: any;
  allTreats: any;
  noDupes: any;
  selectedAll: any;
  isChecked: boolean;
  showTreats: any;
  checkedList: string[] = [];

constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.getTreats();
}
  getTreats(){
  this.grocery_list = [

      {"fruit": "apple", "veggie": "lettuce", "sweets": ["cookies", "cake"]},
      {"fruit": "orange", "veggie": "asparagus", "sweets": ["cookies", "ice cream"]},
      {"fruit": "apple", "veggie": "carrots", "sweets": ["No Data", "cake"]},
      {"fruit": "apple", "veggie": "lettuce", "sweets": ["cookies", "No Data"]},
    ];

  this.treats = this.grocery_list.map(x => x.sweets); 
  this.box = [].concat.apply([],this.treats);
  this.noDupes = Array.from(new Set(this.box));
  this.allTreats = Array.from(this.box)
  }

// this is where the check/uncheck logic starts
    onCheckboxChange(option, event) {
      let eChecked = event.target.checked;
     if(eChecked) {
       this.grocery_list.forEach(x => {
         x.sweets.forEach(y => {
           if (y === option){
             this.checkedList.push(x);
           }
         });
       });
// this is the part that isn't working
     } else {
       this.checkedList.forEach(c, i => {
         c.sweets.forEach(k => {
           // if 'sweet' name = option, remove its array object
           if (k === option) {
             this.checkedList.splice(i, this.checkedList.length)
           }
         })

         }) 
     }
     }
}
```

Comment: `.forEach(c, i => {...})` is not right, is it?  It should be `.forEach((c, i) => {...})`.

Comment: You are def correct and I've updated my stackblitz so thanks for that! Still not removing the correct items when unchecking but that def helped...

Comment: you only want to remove 1 item, right? 
this.checkedList.splice(i, 1) // the index of the item and how many items to remove.

Comment: Part of the issue is that the splice won't work at all since the original array is now referenced as an object. I have tried this.checkedList.splie(i, this.checkedList[i]) to get all references but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find a simpler approach that solves the problem

```
 onCheckboxChange(option, event) {
  let checkedState = event.target.checked;
  if(checkedState === true)
    this.checkedList = this.checkedList.concat(this.grocery_list.filter(item => item.sweets.includes(option)))
  else
    this.checkedList = this.checkedList.filter(item => !item.sweets.includes(option));
    // the above code checks for items which contains sweets array with selected option and keeps only those which doesn't
  }
```

**Update**
change the below type

```
checkedList: any[] = []; // or create an interface based on your grocery_list
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting this error: Property 'sweets' does not exist on type 'string'. This is part of my question that folks seem to be missing. this.checkList is an array and the first time I loop through it, all is fine. When looping again to check which items to remove, it's no longer able to be iterated over as an array.

Comment: You are pushing objects into checkedList as far as I can see in the code. `this.checkedList.push(x);` I cannot know how it is getting converted to a string elsewhere in the code

Comment: Correct, I am and it's working when initially displaying matching values. Once we get to the 'else' part of the code, it's an object and I can't loop through it.

Comment: unless you are mutating it somewhere not shown in the code above, it should not get converted into an object from an array! the problem cannot be in the code above.

Comment: Right, that's the main issue. I'll take a look at what you've added above and see if that helps me find the culprit.

Comment: The above code is just a neater way to write the same logic. check if you are using this.checkedList in the template in a wrong way or share the rest of the code

Comment: sorry, missed the blitz. will check

Comment: The error can never be "discovered" by reading code since it is a typo in ts and the data never changes in reality.

Comment: Ah, ok, I had previously tried 'checkedList: [];' and it would fail so I needed the 'any'. This should take care of it, thanks!

Comment: I had a typo in my code, the find does not work, you must use includes or indexOf